# Should one perform a calculation in a DTO model or in the destination entity model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dto

I'm currently creating various entities in ASP.NET Core 2.2 with accompanying DTOs for a Web API. The client application would submit a DTO object to the relevant controller action. There using the AutoMapper, this would be mapped from the DTO object to an entity object. The resulting entity object would be saved to an entity framework repository which at this moment would be a Microsoft SQL database. For brevity let's assume that the time zones would be irrelevant in this case.

I was just wondering which approach would be more appropriate or to even have not have the calculation in either the DTO or Entity but perhaps within the Controller action.

*Note: The actual code is more complicated and involves various calculations for various properties, I have simply chosen a simple case to illustrate my question.*

**Approach #1**

```cs
// Entity
public class EventTimes
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours => (decimal)(End - Start).TotalHours;
}

// DTO
public class EventTimesDto
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

**Approach #2**

```cs
// Entity
public class EventTimes
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }
}

// DTO
public class EventTimesDto
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours => (decimal)(End - Start).TotalHours;
}
```

Comment: Iam using second approach because entity contain raw data and model can transform them into desired output. If eg. presentation layer need totalHours Iam doing this in model instead of entity. In entity it would lead for endless modifications. If you will need TotalHoursWithoutHour it belong to the model instead of entity IMHO. Other model can need date differently.

Comment: @daremachine +1 Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @ProgrammerMan Your question is too broad and in my opinion it's impossible to give a correct answer without a lot of additional context. Do you intend to save this data? Does the time zone matters? What is the format of the date? As far as I'm concerned this could go as far as the presentation logic.You DTO already has all necessary  data to make this calculation. Depending on your use case you can make an argument for virtually any layer of your system. There are better places like SE `Code Review` where you can post this question.

Comment: @Leron Thanks for the feedback. I have added more detail now to the original question. The data would be saved through Entity Framework into a Microsoft SQL database. Time zones in this scenario do not currently matter.

Comment: Option 3: Neither. Keep database entities and DTOs for APIs as POCO objects and have a separate ViewModel if you want to transform the data for display. Now you can evolve your API and your storage format without affecting your views and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the actual context. Is the `EventTimes` an entity or is it rather part of your domain model?

Either way I would not put it in the **dto** as this is really just for transferring data, so it should not contain any logic (besides maybe validation).

Since the responsibility for this calculation is neither part of the dto, nor the entity model's, you could put the heavy calculation in an `EventTimesCalculator` something like this:

```
public class EventTimesCalculator
{
    public decimal CalculateTotalHours(EventTimes eventTimes)
    {
        return (decimal)(eventTimes.End - eventTimes.Start).TotalHours;
    }
}
```

If the `EventTimes` is part of your business layer / domain model, a more appropriate way would be to have a `GetTotalHours()` method inside of the model, instead of a property. Of course you would need to map it to the persistence model, if you want to save that information. Then again, since this information can be calculated, you don’t need to persist it at all, mainly because the logic might change (example: exclude breaks, interruptions or such).

My advice is to stop thinking in terms of database entities (which I assume you meant above).

At the end, it’s rather a detail where you put the calculation logic, more importantly is to have a straight forward design. Is the application monolithic put that logic in your layer that contains the business logic. Is it a distributed architecture, handle the calculation for the model in the service responsible for Eventing. Is it just a small API, keep it simple, put it where you or your team would expect it the most.

Comment: Thanks. The reminder that DTOs are not supposed to contain any logic already rules out approach #2. I think the most appropriate solution would be to either place such logic within the API controller action or as you stated as a method as part of the entity and to have the controller action call it after mapping the properties from the DTO to the entity.

Comment: I've also added a simple example for an `EventTimesCalculator` service, which you can put in your fitting layer.

Comment: "Since the responsibility for this calculation is neither part of the dto", but how do you come to that conclusion?, at the end is just a value that is always interested to know somewhere, and it only makes sense to an instance of a class, so why have extra bluff in a needles static class

Comment: I come to that conclusion because Data Transfer Objects just transfer data. If they did otherwise, those were no DTOs. Besides the fact that he has a real EventTimes model and one could argue that the calculation should belong there as part of the domain logic, which is a fair point. 
Other than that, the extra bluff is usually for the purpose of isolated unit testing, code structuring and reusability. Surely you can skip patterns and practices and just write transaction scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Iam using second approach because entity can contain raw which can be modified by application flow.

Common pattern [Data transfer object (DTO)](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) is exactly what you want for transport data between application layers which can transform data into desired output. Dto can't contain business logic but also can "prepare", "reduce" data which destination need.

**For example:**
If presentation layer need totalHours Iam doing this in model instead of entity.
Doing this in entity it would lead for endless modifications.

**Another example** can be user's full name `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `AcademicDegree`.

Entity can hold all of them but

- one presentation need [academic degree] [firstname] [lastname] and
- second need data in different format such as [lastname]
  [firstname] [academic degree].

It is good keep property that make desired format in specific DTO instead of entity IMHO.

I in ASP.NET Core do this in onion architecture and view models and from my experience is easy to manage, change, prepare data for front-end or layers instead of change something in core.

If someone disagrees with me please let comment I like learn something new.

Hope it helps